# Edit XML contents of gzip file

Tags: xml, windows, macos, cross-platform, gzip

I need to make an application that can edit the XML contents inside a gzipped file.

Is there any software I can use that's cross compatible with Win/Mac that can do this?

- open the gzip
- search the xml file inside the gzip for a specific tag
- convert the contents of the tag from hex to ascii
- edit the ascii
- convert the contents back from ascii to hex
- save the xml file inside the gzip file

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "save the xml file inside the gzip file".  You'd need to gunzip the xml file, edit it, and re-gzip it.

Comment: I see. Any easy cross platform way to do that? Python seems to come to mind :/

Comment: [zlib](http://zlib.net) can decompress and compress to the gzip format, and works across all platforms.